# How to show JSON in HTML table on Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to show data in HTML table on Angular 10 and I get this error `Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`. I have this JSON below:

```json
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "petr4.SA",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-10-23",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-10-23": {
            "1. open": "20.9400",
            "2. high": "21.1400",
            "3. low": "20.5400",
            "4. close": "20.5700",
            "5. volume": "61328500"
        },
        "2020-10-22": {
            "1. open": "20.1000",
            "2. high": "20.8400",
            "3. low": "20.0500",
            "4. close": "20.8400",
            "5. volume": "98359400"
        }
}
```

My model class:

```js
export class Candle{
    date: Date;
    open: string;
    high: string;
    low: string;
    close: string;
    volume: string;
}
```

My service class:

```js
export class CandleService {

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  findAll(): Observable<Candle[]>{
    return this.http.get<Candle[]>(`${API_CONFIG.baseUrl}`);
  }
}
```

and lastly HTML:

```html
<div class="container-analyzer">
    <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Open</th>
          <th>High</th>
          <th>Low</th>
          <th>Close</th>
          <th>Volume</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let candle of ativoData">
            <tr>
                <td>{{candle.data}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.open}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.high}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.low}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.close}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.volume}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: the error here seems straightforward;  your data is neither an array nor iterable.

Comment: Because "Only arrays and iterables are allowed"  in `ngFor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function to transform your data into an array so that it can be displayed on the template.

Write a function like this

```js
  transformData(rawData: any) {
    let processedData: Array<Candle> = [];
    Object.keys(rawData["Time Series (Daily)"] || []).forEach(key => {
      processedData.push({
        date: new Date(key),
        open: rawData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["1. open"],
        high: rawData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["2. high"],
        low: rawData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["3. low"],
        close: rawData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["4. close"],
        volume: rawData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["5. volume"]
      });
    });
    return processedData;
  }
```

and call it once the data is received from the service

something like

```js
this.ativoData = this.transformData(this.rawData);
```

and in temple

```html
<div class="container-analyzer">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Open</th>
            <th>High</th>
            <th>Low</th>
            <th>Close</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let candle of ativoData">
            <tr>
                <td>{{candle.date | date}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.open}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.high}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.low}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.close}}</td>
                <td>{{candle.volume}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is a working [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/s64527216o?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing complex code you can use Mat-Angular ( material design components ) table ( https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview ) to construct your table. You can easily manipulate data that you want to show on the screen.

Comment: how is this "complex code"?  besides the fact that even using this library you are suggesting, the same problem still remains;  the data isn't in an array.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see ativoData defined, and even if it is, it's not an array nor an iterable.

You need to get the value of the `"Time Series (Daily)"` object and convert it to an array (you can use `Object.entries()` to do this) and store it into the value `ativoData`.

Then, in your `*ngFor` in your HTML, you also need to define your index to access each date. Basically, it would look like `*ngFor="let candle of ativoData; index as i"`.

Lastly, in your interpolation by using the given index, you can access each value which would look like this:

```
{{candle[i]}} // this will give you the date
{{candle[i].open}} // now you can access each value of the date
{{candle[i].high}}
{{candle[i].low}}
.
.
.
so on and so forth
```